# Calculating FPS Javascript ( Do I make something wrong? )

Tags: javascript, frame-rate

Here is my calculateFPS function:

```
function calculateFPS() {
  const now = performance.now();
  if(fps.lastCalledTime !== null) {
    fps.counter++;

    const secondsPerFrame = (now - fps.lastCalledTime) / 1000;
    fps.totalFPS += 1 / secondsPerFrame;
    if(fps.counter === 20) {
      fps.fps = Math.round(fps.totalFPS / fps.counter);
      fps.totalFPS = 0;
      fps.counter = 0;
    }
  }
  fps.lastCalledTime = now;
}
```

Here is my fps global object:

```
let fps = {
  lastCalledTime: null,
  fps: 60,
  counter: 0,
  totalFPS: 0,
}
```

However when I see my game slowing down (the game is Mowing (if I translated it correctly)) basically the FPS should go down... instead it goes up to `400` - `500`

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the time difference between two function calls as such

```
let then = performance.now();
let now;
let frame = 1000/60;

function animate() {

    now = performance.now();
    console.log(((now - then)/frame) * 60);
    then = now;

}

setInterval(animate, frame);
```

Comment: I've read the post that using Date.now() is not good in that kind of function. Also I don't need to calculate time difference between two functions.. I need FPS and please tell me why am I getting larger FPS when the game gets slower? Shouldn't it be inversed? And even why do I get sometimes FPS between 400 - 500 FPS (WTF?? 400 - 500 FPS isn't even possible on todays machine)... I am not satisfied with your answer so I don't mark it as correct answer

Comment: It also works with performance.now. You are thinking too complicated, you don't need to have a fps counter that adds 1 every frame. In this example, the difference in milliseconds is divided by the amount of milliseconds that one frame should take in an ideal situation, which is 1000/60. You can see a working jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/w4waap2p/3/  The console will show a fps count fluctuating between 59 and 61 depending on your environment.